# Graph of this insane double integral.

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

Define: $g(z) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{1}{z})$

Define: $f(x) = \int_1^x \Big(\int_1^y g(z)~\, dz\Big) dy~:~ \forall x > 0$

I just want to plot $f$ on the Cartesian plane to see what it looks like. Unfortunately Desmos crashes when I input $f$ and Wolfram Alpha doesn't like it either. This does not come from any textbook question or anything, I just made it up. My motivation for $f$ is that it should be strictly convex on its domain, but something strange that I can't even really describe yet should happen as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ (I think). I want to see what happens.

Does anyone have a tool/program powerful enough to graph this function near 0?

Comment: Any program that uses numerical evaluation of $g(z)$ will have problem integrating it around $0$, since the function is oscillating too fast. The numerical integration will not converge.

Comment: It is hard to visualise because $\sin(1/x)$ takes every value in $[-1,1]$ in every neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: +George Coote Yes that's exactly why I chose $\sin(1/x)$

Comment: +Andrei I'm not familiar with numerical integration. How does it work? Even so I can't see why it wouldn't converge since the integral itself is bounded?